# Programmaticaly use catalog permission based on user group

Tags: magento2, catalog, permissions

Is there a way to restrict catalog / product page based on user group (for example, if my user is in the group "A", he will see only product for the group "A") ?

Ideally by avoiding paid extension if anyone know reply me.

Answer (score 0):

Without an proper extension, i belive that the answer wouldn't be too short. Perhaps, i've already done many things using string position on php ([reference here](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.strpos.php)) with javascript too. Let me give an example, here is the code on my Magento 1.7 that shows the menu items:

```
 <?php if ($categories): ?>
            <?php echo $this->renderCategoriesMenuHtml(TRUE, 0, 'level-top'); ?>
        <?php endif; ?>
```

You could do a string verification, like:

```
<?php If { the URL contains url string of cat. A or B, ?> <style>.levelx .nav-X { display: none; } </style> <?php } ?>
```

Comment: I should be more specific : it's on the catalog, not on the menu